# can we search for a list of DocuSign envelopes, providing a custom field value?

Tags: docusignapi

here is the scenario. I am trying to find a way via DocuSign API calls to tag a documents with a unique Id and send it to DocuSign for further processing. Then later I want to get the list of those documents being tagged with that unique ID.

what I came up with was to create an envelope custom field and add the unique ID as its value, so later I be able to search for any documents with that value in the custom field. documentation says it is possible, but there is no example how to do the search. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to get back envelopes or documents? If it's envelopes, then you're correct in your design to use envelope level custom fields. Below is the query:

{{baseUrl}}/envelopes?custom_field=customfieldname=value&from_date=2018-01-01

customfieldname is the id defined by you when you create custom fields.
from_date is mandatory for perf reasons.

This query will get you all your envelopes that match this custom field value, and then you can call getDocuments for that envelope. This should be your design even if you operate at a Document level, simply fill the envelope custom field based on your Documents.

If you're goal is instead to have a single query to search all Documents, I don't think that's possible and also unlikely to be performant.

Comment: Thanks for the response. it was very helpful.